# how get length or size of Resultset in java

Tags: java, jdbc

I want to know how many rows in result set after executing the particular query

```
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

how get the size of rs???
thanx in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you just want the number of rows in the `ResultSet`, you can do :

```
int size= 0;
if (rs != null)   
{  
  rs.beforeFirst();  
  rs.last();  
  size = rs.getRow();  
}
```

Comment: That is only guaranteed to work for scrollable resultsets, type forward only resultsets should throw an `SQLException` when `beforeFirst()` or `last()` are called (although some implementations don't do that).

Comment: This would mean reading the entire table over the network and throwing away the data after, it would be far better to simply execute a count(*) sql query instead

Answer (score 4):

by doing while loop:

```
int size=0;
while (rs.next()) {
    size++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need not to iterate it and count the number of rows. You can try the following easy approach

```
boolean b = rs.last();
int numberOfRecords = 0;
if(b){
    numberOfRecords = rs.getRow();
}
```